# How to get values from GET request in node.js and use it in the POST request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Am new to Node.js and mysql. How can I get the results from GET request and use it in the POST in node.js

For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql =  require('mysql');

var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
        user : 'root',
        host : 'localhost',
        database : '',
        password : ''
});


app.get('/get/pension/:empid', function (req, res) {
  const empid = parseInt(req.params.empid);
  connection.query("SELECT pensionid from pension where empid = ?",[empid], function(error,rows,fields){
    if(!error){
      console.log('connected inside');
      res.send(rows);   
    }
    else {
      console.log('error 1'  + JSON.stringify(error,undefined,2));
    }
  });
});
```

I want to use the pensionid from the GET request and insert into another table.

```
app.post('/post/vaccination/:petid/:speciesName/:vaccineType/:userName', function (req, res) {
  //should it be request.body? const {pension} =  request.body
  connection.query("INSERT INTO AnotherTable(col1) VALUES(?)",[pension], function(error,rows,fields){
    if(!error){
      console.log('Added');     
    }
    else {
      console.log('error 1' + JSON.stringify(error,undefined,2));
    }
  });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the request body of a post request in the `req` object.

To parse the `post` body you have to add `body-parser` package to parse the request body.

First install the `body-parser` package.

```
>$ npm i --save body-parser
```

Then add the the package in your project file.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // To parse the Json data
```

And then access your body in `req` object.

```
app.post('/post/vaccination/:petid/:speciesName/:vaccineType/:userName', function (req, res) {
    const {pension} =  req.body;
    connection.query("INSERT INTO AnotherTable(col1) VALUES(?)", [pension], function (error, rows, fields) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('Added');
        }
        else {
            console.log('error 1' + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        }
    });
});
```

**Full working code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: '',
    password: ''
});

app.post('/post/vaccination/:petid/:speciesName/:vaccineType/:userName', function (req, res) {
    //should it be request.body? const {pension} =  request.body
    connection.query("INSERT INTO AnotherTable(col1) VALUES(?)", [pension], function (error, rows, fields) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('Added');
            res.status(201).send("added");
        }
        else {
            console.log('error 1' + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            res.status(500).send('error 1' + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        }
    });
});
```

> Please note that you have to send response in both error and success case.

Comment: body-parser is now added to the Express framework. app.use(express.json())